# SQLAlchemy: Conditional autoincrement

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relational-database

I want to create a flat forum, where threads are no separate table, with a composite primary key for posts.

So posts have two fields forming a natural key: `thread_id` and `post_number`, where the further is the ID of the thread they are part of, and the latter is their position in the thread. if you aren’t convinced, check below the line.

My problem is that i don’t know how to tell SQLAlchemy

> when committing the addition of new `Post` instances with thread_id `tid`, look up how many posts with thread_id `tid` exist, and autoincrement from that number on.

---

Why do i think that schema is a good idea? because it’s natural and performant:

```
class Post(Base):
    number    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    thread_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    title     = Column(Text) #nullable for not-first posts
    text      = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    ...
PAGESIZE = 10
#test
tid = 5
page = 4
```

Entire Thread (query):

```
thread5 = session.query(Post).filter_by(thread_id=5)
```

Thread title:

```
title = thread5.filter_by(number=0).one().title
```

Thread page

```
page4 = thread5.filter(
    Post.number >= (page    * PAGESIZE),
    Post.number < ((page+1) * PAGESIZE)).all()
#or
page4 = thread5.offset(page * PAGESIZE).limit(PAGESIZE).all()
```

Number of pages:

```
ceil(thread5.count() / PAGESIZE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this with [an SQL expression as a default value](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#sql-expressions) (see the `default` argument). Give it a callable like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

def maxnumber_for_threadid(context):
    return post_table.select([func.max(post_table.c.number)]).where(post_table.c.thread_id==context.current_parameters['thread_id'])
```

I'm not absolutely sure you can return an sql expression from a default callable--you may have to actually execute this query and return a scalar value inside the callback. (The cursor should be available from the `context` parameter.)

However, I strongly recommend you do what @kindall says and just use another auto-incrementing sequence for the `number` column.  What you want to do is actually very tricky to get right even without SQLAlchemy. For example, if you are using an MVCC database you need to introduce special row-level locking so that the number of rows with a matching `thread_id` does not change while you are running the transaction. How this is done is database-dependent.  For example with MySQL InnoDB, you need to do something like this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT MAX(number)+1 FROM posts WHERE thread_id=? FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO posts (thread_id, number) VALUES (?, ?); -- number is from previous query
COMMIT;
```

If you didn't use `FOR UPDATE`, then conceivably another connection trying to insert a new post into the same thread at the same time could have gotten the same value for `number`.

So rather than being performant, post inserts are actually quite slow (relatively speaking) because of the extra query and locking required.

All this is resolved by using a separate sequence and not worrying about post number incrementing only within a thread_id.

Comment: nice! thanks for the answer even if you actually think another way would be better. but while i agree that the other way will be easier to accomplish, i still think that it isn’t expensive in the average case: one transaction should generally only create one post, so the only requirement would be to execute the query/insertion you posted in one transaction per post.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a global post number that increments for posts in *any* thread. Then you don't need to figure out the right number to use for a given thread. A given thread, then, might have posts numbered 7, 20, 42, 51, and so on. This does not matter because you can easily get the number of posts in the thread from the size of the recordset you get back from the query, and you can easily number the posts in the HTML output separately from the actual post numbers.

Comment: that’s what everybody does, but it seem so arbitrary. i specifically had the idea to use the information that’s already there and not introduce arbitrary additional IDs. because the post number would actually mean something, and the post ID would not (nobody cares in which total order stuff was posted, and if someone did, we’d just sort by creation date)